# CSS3 hover transition effect scale

Tags: css

I seem to have a problem with the transition on hover.  When it reaches the end of the   transition it jumps back to the normal scale. Dont know where is the problem.Any IDEA what should I do with it?

```css
#image1 {
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 350px;
top: 100px;
left: 3%;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px;
transition: All 0.900s linear;
-webkit-transition: All 0.900s linear;
-moz-transition: All 0.900s linear;
-o-transition: All 0.900s linear;
transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1)  skew(0deg)  translate(0px);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1)  skew(0deg)  translate(0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1)  skew(0deg)  translate(0px);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1)  skew(0deg)  translate(0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1)  skew(0deg)  translate(0px);
}
#image1:hover {
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 350px;
top: 100px;
left: 3%;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px;
transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1.234)  skew(0deg)  translateX(150px)  translateY(50px);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1.234)  skew(0deg)  translateX(150px)  translateY(50px);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1.234)  skew(0deg)  translateX(150px)  translateY(50px);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1.234)  skew(0deg)  translateX(150px)  translateY(50px);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg)  scale(1.234)  skew(0deg)  translateX(150px)  translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="image1">
```

Comment: In what browser does this occur?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Chrome. Sidenote: [You only really need the `-ms-` and `-webkit-` prefixes.](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) That should clean up your CSS :) [The transition probably doesn't need any prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) unless you need to support an ancient Safari version.

Comment: I tried it in both browsers and in chrome the hover doesnt work at all

Answer (score 2):

The hover event moves the very element on which the same hover event is listened. So once the transition has ended, your element isn't hovered anymore as soon as you move your cursor just a tiny bit.

You should try wrapping your image inside an immobile container and listen to the hover on this container.

**EDIT:** added this snippet:

```css
#image1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 3%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: All 0.900s linear;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.900s linear;
  -moz-transition: All 0.900s linear;
  -o-transition: All 0.900s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
}
#container:hover #image1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 3%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.234) skew(0deg) translateX(150px) translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.234) skew(0deg) translateX(150px) translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.234) skew(0deg) translateX(150px) translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.234) skew(0deg) translateX(150px) translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.234) skew(0deg) translateX(150px) translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="image1">
</div>
```

Comment: Was just about to post something simililar. Something like this would do the trick: `#container:hover #image1, #image1:hover { }` :)

Comment: yes for `#container:hover #image1 { }` but I don't see the point of the second part, as hovering the image will trigger the hover on the container anyway.